# Rotate MapView using Compass orientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-3gs

Is it possible to have an embedded `MKMapView` rotate to always face the direction the iPhone is facing?  Basically I want to mimic the Map app rotation feature on my own app.

I see that the iPhone SDK does not expose the functionality.  However, I wonder if it would work to rotate the entire view using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotate`.  Would it affect tapping and zooming?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To rotate the mapView but not the annotations you could use the following code to compensate for the maps rotation.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
  double rotation = newHeading.magneticHeading * 3.14159 / 180;
  CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, -23); // The anchor point for your pin

  [mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotation)];

  [[mapView annotations] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    MKAnnotationView * view = [mapView viewForAnnotation:obj];

    [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)];
    [view setCenterOffset:CGPointApplyAffineTransform(anchorPoint, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation))];

  }];

}
```

---

Another sollution is using a new method that has been added in iOS 5 to MKMapView.

Take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

`- (void)setUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated;`

Comment: What about bringing this feature in iOS6? Can we rotate map north oriented? I am tried to orient the map, but its a fail.

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm that it works fine.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * currentHeading.magneticHeading * 3.14159 / 180)];
```

`mapView` is my MKMapView instance

Comment: The above code works to rotate the mapview, but what about the annotations? How would the transform be applied to those as well?

Comment: I have posted an answer for your question below.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution in swift 3.0. Make sure to put the line in `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` or it will ignore it

```
public func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView)
{
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: false)
}
```

If you don't want the map to center on the user location you might do something like this

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
{
    if(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(mapView.centerCoordinate))
    {
        mapView.camera.heading = newHeading.trueHeading
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the 3.0 iPhone Application Programming Guide under `Device Support` you'll find information on the magnetometer (aka compass). Once you start getting heading information (through the `didUpdateHeading` method) you should be able to get the compass data then use that to calculate the proper rotation transform value to apply to the map view.

Not sure if it handles zooming. In the standard map application I've noticed that compass heading tracking stops as soon as you start pinch-zooming.

Also, keep in mind that location directions are in degrees whereas transform rotation angles are in radians.

Answer (score -2):

if you use a navigationVontroller try this:

```
//For Left button
 MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem 
                                                 alloc]initWithMapView:_mapView];

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;


// For Right Button
     MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem 
                                                     alloc]initWithMapView:_mapView];

     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```