# SetUserTrackingMode not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, mkmapview

I am programming a map app on iPhone and want the map to rotate as the user changes his direction. I have read most of the posts on stackoverflow. Most of them suggest the use of `setUserTrackingMode` with `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` if we are working with iOS 5 or later. This does not seem to work with me for some reason. Following is my code:

```
-(IBAction)getLocation  //This is a button
{
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;  //mapView is the instance of MKMapView
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
}
```

This only shows the user location but if I move the phone, it doesn't rotate. 
One more thing is, I downloaded a project from internet, and I included this line. It worked there only for the first time. I have no idea why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to do this is to include an [`MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mkusertrackingbarbuttonitem&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html&ei=zYorUK3UKIHAhAeyk4CYBA&usg=AFQjCNHJN58Ol9KlWqYV9EfaG7ER911pVg) instead of creating your own button. It acts exactly the same as the button in the iOS 5 Maps app and is easy to set up.

Here's how to use it:

```
// You should have an outlet to your map view called mapView
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *userTrackingButton;
userTrackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];

// You need an outlet to your toolbar too
[self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:userTrackingButton]];
```

Comment: I added a toolbar in the .xib file and then in the `ViewController.h`, I have:

`-(IBAction)track:(id)sender;`

Now, in the `ViewController.m` file, in `viewDidLoad`:

`MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *myButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
[myButton setTarget:self];
[myButton setAction:@selector(track:)];
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myButton, nil];
[myButton release];`

and then somewhere else I defined `track` and added `showsUserLocation` and `setUserTrackingMode`.
I am simulating the location too, still map doesn't rotate.

Comment: That button takes care of target and action. All you need to do is give it your map view and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this, Can you please elaborate...
so do I just write `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];`? By doing this I don't see it getting added in the final view (I have a single view application), or do I put a toolbar in the .xib file and then link it?

Comment: You'll need to put it in the toolbar to for it to appear. I've updated my answer with a little code. Make sure you have the outlets to a map and toolbar using the same names as I used.

Answer (score 6):

You need to wait for the 'MapView' finish loading...

**follow:**

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
}
```

**follow & heading:**

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change "Animated" to "animated" and try again

Comment: Sorry for the typo... it still doesn't work, but program runs fine.

Comment: Is there some way you could confirm the userTrackingMode has really been set? If there is a loop or an action you can trigger by hand, add some debug text that prints out the trackingMode. If that really is set (and your device does actually have a compass) then there is no reason it shouldn't rotate like other map apps.

Comment: I searched as per your suggestions and I found a similar issue `[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941763/setting-mkusertrackingmodefollowwithheading)`. There, they set the value 2 for `MKUserFollowWithHeading' and then print it. Can anybody explain how to do that? Also, they report some erroneous behaviour. It seems to be solved by setting `mapview's` delegate as `self`

Comment: can somebody please explain me how to print the value of `setUserTrackingMode` mentioned above in this comment?

Comment: If ([mapview userTrackingMode] == mkusertrackingmodeFollow) NSLog(@"follow");

Comment: Ok, I tested out the above command and I can see `follow` getting printed onto the console. I tried setting mapView's delegate as self, but still it didn't work. I am running this app on simulator, by any chance, is that the reason of this behavior? I don't think simulator plays any role here because I have seen it working on simulator.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, when I set `mapView's` delegate as `self`, I get a warning:
`Assigning to id <MKMapViewDelegate> from incompatible type 'FirstMapViewController *'`
what does this mean?

Comment: Yes if you are using this on a simulator you won't get a heading, unless your iOS device is plugged in and has a compass. Your mac doesn't have a compass does it? As for the delegate problem you should ask a new question. The answer will be to mark your MapViewController as implementing the MapViewDelegate protocol.